# Floquet Theory theorem clarification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my ODE course, we have the following theorem

The number $\mu_0$ is a Floquet multiplier of the Floquet system $x^\prime =A(t)x$ if and only if there is a nontrivial solution $x$ such that 
$$x(t+\omega)=\mu_0 x(t),$$
for al $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  Consequently, the floquet system has a nontrivial periodic solution of period $\omega$ if and only if $\mu_0=1$ is a Floquet multiplier.  Also, if $\mu_0=-1$, then there is a nontrivial periodic solution with period $2\omega$.

Could someone explain how the consequences follow from the theorem?  I don't understand how they follow, and I'm assuming that I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're missing something obvious.

With $\mu_0 = 1$, $x(t+\omega) = x(t)$.

With $\mu_0 = -1$, 
$x(t+2\omega) = - x(t + \omega) = x(t)$.